# Does computer strength vary in Mario Party?

Tags: super-mario-party

Yesterday night, me and 2 of my friends were playing Super Mario Party on my Nintendo Switch, along with 1 normal level CPU (Wario). During this session, the AI seemed to play much better than it normally does. It's possible we were all just playing worse than usual, but I know that Mario Kart has a [rivals system](https://www.mariowiki.com/Rival), where some AI players will play better than usual. So this got me wondering if Mario Party has a similar mechanic, where AI players will sometimes play better than they normally would.

**Does Super Mario Party have a system similar to rivals from Mario Kart? Will the AI sometimes play better than their chosen difficulty setting would suggest?**

Comment: I believe this is a valid question, so I've gone ahead and cleaned the wording up to hopefully make it more clear what is actually being asked here.